# VBA Web Scraper Only Works on First Column

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I recently developed a web scraper that uses VBA and Selenium. The purpose of the macro is to go through all of the links in every row in the first column in Sheet1, scrape the web content, send the results to the same cells in Sheet3 (i.e. the links that it opens in cell (9.1) in Sheet1 will be scraped and the results sent to cell (9.1) in Sheet3) and then go through the links in the second column and so on.

I created it by having two for loops (one to go through all the columns and then an inner for loop to go through all of the rows in each column). The scraper gets the right content and the loop for the rows works fine. However, the macro stops after processing all of the links in the first column instead of going to Column B to repeat the process.

I am assuming that there is something wrong with my outer for loop for the columns. Here is my code:

```vb
Sub scraping_web()
    Dim chrm As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim row_no, col_no As Integer
    Dim visitpage
    Dim attributionlink
    Dim fullHTMLlink
    Dim alttag

    row_no = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set chrm = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    chrm.Start
    For j = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column
        For i = 3 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            visitpage = Sheet1.Cells(i, j).Value
            chrm.Get (visitpage)

            chrm.FindElementById ("attribution-html")
            chrm.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]").Click
            chrm.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/figure/img").Text

            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:08")
            attributionlink = chrm.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/figure/img").Attribute("src")

            alttag = chrm.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/figure/img").Attribute("alt")

            fullHTMLlink = "<img src=""" & attributionlink & """" & " " & "alt=" & """" & "This is a Creative Commons image with the title " & alttag & "" & """" & ">"
            Sheet3.Cells(i, j).Value = fullHTMLlink & chrm.FindElementById("attribution-html").Text
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my outer for loop or if you have another solution that works better.

Thanks!

Edit: MY title initially said "first row" but I meant to say column

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column` should probably be: `Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column` always returns `1`.